# maven-publish plugin gradle only publish specific module

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

I'm developing a multi-module android project using gradle build.

I'm using maven-publish plugin to publish artifact to sonartype nexus.

The current setup is inside every module there is a publication job

```
plugins{
    id(Plugins.kotlinAndroidApplication)
    id(Plugins.kotlinAndroid)
    id(Plugins.kotlinAndroidExtensions)
    id(Plugins.mavenPublish)
    id(Plugins.dokkaAndroid)
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
        credentials {
            username = project.properties["mavenUser"] as? String
            password = project.properties["mavenPassword"] as? String
        }
        url = https://mynexus
    }
    }
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenAar") {
            groupId = rootProject.extra.get("groupId") as String
            artifactId = rootProject.extra.get("artifactId") as String
            version = (rootProject.extra.get("versionName") as String) + (if (project.hasProperty("release")) "" else "-SNAPSHOT")

            from(components["android"])
            //artifact(tasks["javadocJar"])
            artifact(tasks["dokkaJar"])
        }
    }
}
```

When my Jenkin CI build the project with deploy = true, every module will be published. The problem is some module depend on other, so the dependency module will be published twice. Re-deploy module with same version is not allowed on release nexus maven repo.

Anyway to only publish certain module only or to ensure every module is only deploy once?

Comment: Try removing `from(components["android"])` and instead link the aar file as `artifact(...)`

Comment: thanks. can u help evaluate a bit more detail? any sample code is much appreciate

Comment: `artifact("${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar")`

Comment: that mean they will be republish but different name?

Comment: No, it will take the `artifactId` value

Comment: thanks. not so understand the command: ```artifact("${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar")```. what does it do?

Comment: it will use the generated aar as a maven artifact during the publishing task.

Comment: so let summary ```artifact("${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar")``` will use the generated aar and will not republish the module?

Comment: It will publish it anytime you invoke the corresponding publication publishing task.

Comment: then how does it overcome the problem of re republish same version to nexus?

Comment: got this error ```> Invalid publication 'mavenAar': artifact file does not exist: '/opt/jenkins/workspace/emv_feature_config_release_build/dev_sdk/build/outputs/aar/dev_sdk-release.aar'```

Comment: Make sure you first `build` this module, and that the generated aar file location is correct.

Comment: I'm able to publish but the artifact always ends with: ```emv_feature_config_release_build/dev_sdk/unspecified/dev_sdk-unspecified.pom'``` (not correct groupId and no version although these value has already been set)